# Selenium Problems in PyCharm -- Everything Seems Properly Updated, Cannot Use Method

Tags: python, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I'm on a Mac Mini running Chrome: Version 115.0.5790.114 (Official Build) (arm64) and just downloaded and installed the Chrome Driver which I found here: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/ - the stable version - Mac-Arm64.

I went in and installed and upgraded selenium and pip, and used this terminal command to make chromedriver executable: chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver.

I've tried two versions of this code to try to pull and print the price element from the website.

**Version 1:  One version pulled up the website but didn't print anything. And the error message I get says that

```
the WebDriver object has no attribute known as "find_element_by_id"
```

but apparently this is still a method that functions inside of selenium?

```
from selenium import webdriver # Importing necessary modules from Selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options # Importing the Options class from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options

chrome_driver_path = "/Users/myusername/Documents/pythonProject1/chromedriver"

options = Options()
options.executable_path = chrome_driver_path

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")
chrome_driver_path = "/Users/myusername/Documents/pythonProject1/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/Coleshome-Computer-Writing-Workstation-Vintage/dp/B0B6V83D3Q/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=dhBqd&content-id=amzn1.sym.5f7e0a27-49c0-47d3-80b2-fd9271d863ca%3Aamzn1.symc.e5c80209-769f-4ade-a325-2eaec14b8e0e&pf_rd_p=5f7e0a27-49c0-47d3-80b2-fd9271d863ca&pf_rd_r=TAX9FJM5MT6DWYCYYMRD&pd_rd_wg=b356N&pd_rd_r=b79c530e-5b03-411d-8957-0ec821732764&ref_=pd_gw_ci_mcx_mr_hp_atf_m")
price = driver.find_element_by_id("priceblock_ourprice")
print(price)
```

**Version 2:  Doesn't print anything or go to the website and returns an error that says:

```
'driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=user_path, options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'"
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

user_path = "/Users/user1/Documents/pythonProject1/chromedriver"

options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=user_path, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/Coleshome-Computer-Writing-Workstation-Vintage/dp/B0B6V83D3Q/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=dhBqd&content-id=amzn1.sym.5f7e0a27-49c0-47d3-80b2-fd9271d863ca%3Aamzn1.symc.e5c80209-769f-4ade-a325-2eaec14b8e0e&pf_rd_p=5f7e0a27-49c0-47d3-80b2-fd9271d863ca&pf_rd_r=TAX9FJM5MT6DWYCYYMRD&pd_rd_wg=b356N&pd_rd_r=b79c530e-5b03-411d-8957-0ec821732764&ref_=pd_gw_ci_mcx_mr_hp_atf_m")
price = driver.find_element_by_id("priceblock_ourprice")
print(price.text)
driver.quit()
```

I'd like to be able to receive the price element from the Amazon site, and then print that out following the implementation of this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Out selenium 4

```
pip install webdriver-manager==4.0.0
pip install selenium==4.10.0
```

CODE:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
print(f"=> Driver Path is: {driver_path}")
s = Service(driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/Coleshome-Computer-Writing-Workstation-Vintage/dp/B0B6V83D3Q/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=dhBqd&content-id=amzn1.sym.5f7e0a27-49c0-47d3-80b2-fd9271d863ca%3Aamzn1.symc.e5c80209-769f-4ade-a325-2eaec14b8e0e&pf_rd_p=5f7e0a27-49c0-47d3-80b2-fd9271d863ca&pf_rd_r=TAX9FJM5MT6DWYCYYMRD&pd_rd_wg=b356N&pd_rd_r=b79c530e-5b03-411d-8957-0ec821732764&ref_=pd_gw_ci_mcx_mr_hp_atf_m")

price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@data-cel-widget="corePriceDisplay_desktop_feature_div"]//span[@class="a-price-whole"]').text
print(price)
driver.quit()
```

OUTPUT:

[image]